# Problema con ajax y servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

Tengo un problema al enviar una fecha desde el servlet java a un jsp para que lo haga en tiempo real

Servlet

```
       case "ConsultarxFecha":
```

//                    int IdPln = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipoPlan"));
                    VOPlan FechaEnvio = new VOPlan();
                    String FechaIni = request.getParameter("EnviarFecha");
                    SimpleDateFormat fo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    Date fechaIni = fo.parse(FechaIni);
                    Date fechaEnviada = null;

```
                FechaEnvio.setFechaInicio(fechaIni);
```

//                    planEnvio.setIdPlan_Tipo(IdPlan);
                    ArrayList MostrarFecha = new DAO.DAOPlan().MostrarFechaxPlan(FechaEnvio);

```
                for (int i = 0; i < MostrarFecha.size(); i++) {
                    VOPlan item = MostrarFecha.get(i);
                    fechaEnviada = item.getFechaInicio();
                }

                response.setContentType("aplication/json");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(fechaEnviada.toString()));
                break;
```

Ajax

```
<script>
    function cargarFecha()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {EnviarFecha: $("#FechaI").val(), Peticion: "ConsultarxFecha"},
            cache: false,
            url: '../SVLAfiliado',
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#FechaF").val(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error cargando los diagnosticos - ' + jqXHR.datos);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código completo del servlet. Es necesario saber cómo estás recibiendo los parámetros en él. Además de eso, me causa curiosidad el problema real que enfrentas, ¿cuál es la necesidad o caso de uso que intentas implementar?

Comment: Lo que dices de ver el código completo lo que pasa es que en el servlet lo hago lo con diferentes peticiones entonces no involucraría la que se esta mostrando 

Lo que desea realizar es que dependiendo la fecha inicial ingresada por defecto ingresa la fecha final ese es mi principal problema 
esto lo realizo con una consulta a la base de datos

Comment: Bueno, primero veo que el parámetro `tipoPlan` no está siendo enviado como parte del json de request. Solo tienes `EnviarFecha` y `Peticion`. Pregunta importante: ¿has revisado el stacktrace **completo**? ¿podrías publicarlo aquí para tener más idea sobre dónde está el problema?

Comment: Si que pena había publicado mal el código, pero pues en la consola cuando trato de hacerlo me muestra el mensaje de alerta y no se que sera

Comment: Ok, ¿puedes mostrar el stacktrace del issue que tienes de lado de Java? ¿O podrías explicar mejor qué problema tienes?

Comment: Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option
Esto es lo que me aparece cuando entro en el debug

Comment: No debug, **stacktrace** por favor. Si no puedes habilitar el debug, entonces usa el debug antiguo que es imprimir en consola/log mensajes que te permiten rastrear dónde puede estar el problema.

Comment: Me puedes decir que es el **stacktrace** en el debug de consola es donde me muestra el error que te comente

Comment: **Stacktrace** es esa traza que aparece cuando se dispara un error. Ejemplo: `java.lang.NullPointerException at ... at ... at ... at ...`. Si tienes tu código dentro de un `try-catch` gigante y en el `catch` tienes `catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }` entonces estás ocultando el stacktrace. Lo mejor es cambiar el manejo de la excepción por lo menos a `e.printStackTrace(System.out);`